# What is this technique where they add a thick sauce and spread it out with the back of a spoon

Tags: presentation

I'm sorry my question is so vague but I'm trying to research a technique but have no idea how to describe it.

If you review the picture below, you can see the orange/yellow splodge! :) I see this technique being used quite a lot but have no idea what it is called.

[image]

Does this have a name or technique associated with it? If not, can some one give an example of how to get this type of consistency. I want to recreate this so the meal looks flash but have no idea!

Comment: Another example can be found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Udzs_MPNpMQ

Comment: I can't speak to technique, but I have seen this referred to as a "chef smear"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen it referred to as a tadpole or a comet but I'm not sure if either of those names are widely used. Either way, there's an excellent video on Youtube about how to do them. You want your sauce or puree to have the consistency of mayonnaise for this particular presentation. Just use a dessert spoon to place a circular blob on the plate, clean the back of the spoon and then drag the spoon back through the puree. The video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_idk-BDeal4&feature=player_detailpage&t=131).

Comment: What an excellent answer, thank you. I will view video after work!

Answer (score 3):

I've heard it referred to on some tv shows (eg, Chopped) as 'spoon push', usually in a derisive way.

Searching on that terms yields some websites that describe it.  For example, from http://www.champagneandhamburgers.com/2012/02/jarret-first-spoon-push.html :

> This could be an opportunity for me to attempt my first "spoon push". For those unfamiliar, the spoon push is an oft bastardized technique used most restaurants just past PF Changs on the swank meter. To add a faux artful element to the dish when plating a sauce, purée or any other semi-viscous component, simply drop some on the plate and "push" your spoon across creating a nice little design.

Comment: It's only *faux* artful if you decide that you don't think it looks nice!